# H5P Instance is duplicated in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, h5p

I'm developing with h5p standalone plugin in react (nextjs), passing the path as prop to a Modal Component which render the h5p activity.

```html
useEffect(() => {
    const initH5p = async (contentLocation) => {
    const { H5P: H5PStandalone } = require('h5p-standalone')
    const h5pPath = `https://cdn.thinkeyschool.com/h5p/${contentLocation}`

    const options = {
      id: 'THINKeyLesson',
      h5pJsonPath: h5pPath,
      frameJs: '/h5p/dist/frame.bundle.js',
      frameCss: '/h5p/dist/styles/h5p.css',
    }
    let element = document.getElementById('h5p_container')
    removeAllChildNodes(element)
    await new H5PStandalone(element, options)

    fireCompleteH5PTopic(H5P)
    setIsLoaderVisible(false)
    }
    initH5p(location)
  }, [location, session.data.user.id, course.slug, topic])
```

With that code, I get two h5p rendered in screen. So I'm using removeAllChildren() to eliminate them from the render.

```
 function removeAllChildNodes(parent) {
    console.log(parent)
    while (parent.firstChild) {
      parent.removeChild(parent.firstChild)
    }
  }
```

That hack is working fine, but when I try to send the xAPI statement to my database, it fires twice

```
const fireCompleteH5PTopic = async (H5P) => {
    H5P.externalDispatcher.on("xAPI", (event) => {
      // console.log('event fired')
      if (event?.data?.statement?.result?.completion) {
        setCounter(counter + 1)
        completeH5PTopic(event, session.data.user.id, course.slug, topic)
        return true
      }
    })
  }
```

Any help regarding why it fires twice? I think it may be related to h5p rendering twice too.

Thanks in advance.

I tried using a state to render only once, but it is not working.

Comment: The `useEffect` hook seems to be run twice. H5P Standalone will create two instances and attach them both, even though you're deleting the first instance's DOM. Also, you're attaching two listeners for xAPI statements that will both fire. The best solution would to make sure that `useEffect` is run only once, or you should simply keep track that the H5P instance has already been created and not do that again - and there is no need for your workaround then.

Comment: Did you find workaround for this issue? I am currently stumbled with the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this:

```
import { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react'
import { Loading } from '../../../Animations/Loading'
import { completeH5PTopic } from '../../../../lib/sinapsis/gamification'
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react' // ES6
import ToastGamification from '../../../Notificaciones/ToastGamification'
import { toast } from 'react-hot-toast'
import { useRef } from 'react'

const POINTS_PER_TOPIC_COMPLETED = 5

const H5PContainer = ({ location, course, topic }) => {
  const H5PStandalone = useMemo(() => require('h5p-standalone').H5P, [])

  const [isLoaderVisible, setIsLoaderVisible] = useState(true)

  let firstTime = true
  const h5pPath = `https://mycdn.com/h5p-v1/${location}`
  const { data } = useSession()
  const user = data?.user
  // console.log(user, 'user')
  const name = ''
  const options = {
    h5pJsonPath: h5pPath,
    frameJs: '/h5p/dist/frame.bundle.js',
    frameCss: '/h5p/dist/styles/h5p.css',
  }
  const h5pRef = useRef(null)

  // console.log('H5PStandalone', H5PStandalone)
  const loadH5PComponent = async () => {
    if (h5pRef.current && window) {
      await new H5PStandalone(h5pRef.current, options)
      setIsLoaderVisible(false)

      window.H5P.externalDispatcher.on('xAPI', (event) => {
        //do something useful with the event
        // console.log(event, 'event')
        // console.log('results:', event.getScore(), '---->', name)
        if (
          event.getScore() > 1 ||
          event.data.statement.verb.display['en-US'] === 'completed'
        ) {
          fireCompleteH5PTopicFn(
            window.H5P,
            user?.id,
            course?.slug,
            topic?.slug,
          )
        }
      })
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    if (firstTime) {
      const hasChildren = h5pRef.current.children
      if (hasChildren.length !== 0) {
        const parent = hasChildren[0].parentNode
        parent.removeChild(hasChildren[0])
      }

      loadH5PComponent()
      firstTime = false
      // setIsLoaderVisible(false)
    }
  }, [name])

  return (
    <div className="w-full h-full ">
      {isLoaderVisible && <Loading />}
      <div id={`h5p-container-${location}`} ref={h5pRef} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default H5PContainer

async function fireCompleteH5PTopicFn(userId, courseSlug, topic) {
  const res = await completeH5PTopic(userId, courseSlug, topic)
  toast.dismiss()
  if (res.status === 200) {
    toast.custom((t) => (
      <ToastGamification
        isVisible={t.visible}
        onDismiss={() => toast.dismiss(t.id)}
        points={POINTS_PER_TOPIC_COMPLETED}
      />
    ))
  }
  return true
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! that's really helpful to go through the goal that I have in mind.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you!